# How to search in TortoiseHg certain word in all changes within all changeset?

Tags: search, mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

Here's what I'd like to do. I know a certain html tag was added in one changeset. It is not mentioned in the description of any changeset but seeing the contents of said changeset would be extremely helpful for me. So, how can I find the particular changeset, in which this certain html tag - primefaces fomponent to be exact - was added to the code?

I can search for words in changeset **descriptions** in the repository, but not within the content of all the changesets in one search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TortoiseHg, go into the search tab - `View` -> `Search` menu, or `Alt-3`

(Note - this is different from the `filter` bar at the top, which only filters revisions)

In the search tab at the bottom, choose "All History" (instead of the default, "Working Copy"), and enter a regular expression search pattern.

You can also enter inclusion and exclusion file patterns to only search certain files - this can speed it up a lot.  Note that unlike the search pattern (which is always regular expression), this is a file match pattern, which could be regular expression (e.g. `re:.*\.html`) or glob (e.g. `glob:**\*.html`).